# SharePoint 2013 REST Syntax: How to Reference Multiple Lookup Field Values

Tags: rest, sharepoint, syntax, lookup

I have a REST call that references the "Title" column from a List we shall call "List A".

So far it looks like this:

items?$select=ID,Title,LookupColumn1/Title&$expand=LookupColumn1

This works - It returns that value of the Title column in List A.

I also have another list, "List B", with a Title column I would like to reference.

How do I expand the second lookup? What is the syntax.

FYI - I have fiddled around and spent nearly an hour on Google, but most of the articles I have found so far are about expanding lookup columns with *multiple values*, not multiple lookups.

Thanks for any help.

Jared

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I worked it out!
For those who wish to know you must specify the expansion column on both sides of the $expand method. Eg:

items?$select=ID,Title,LookupColumn1/Title,LookupColumn2/Title&$expand=LookupColumn1/Title,LookupColumn2/Title